# how to put input from a file to a treemap

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to to put the data  from a scanner object that reads a file into a treemap. Any Suggestions?

Here is code:

```
   public class StudentViewController {
   try {
        Scanner ReadFile= new Scanner(new File(currentFileName));
        Student.ReadStudent(ReadFile);
        studentMap.put



       } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Corrupt File");
        System.out.print(e);
       }
      }
```

Here is my method that reads the data:

```
   public static Student ReadStudent (Scanner sc){

    Student student = new Student(sc.next(),sc.next());
    student.ConcreateID = sc.nextInt();
    NextID = sc.nextInt();
    int gradeNum = sc.nextInt();
    //Loop that runs through the file the number of grades specified for that student,
    //retrieving each grade and adding it into the array for that specific student Object.
    for (int i = 0; i < gradeNum; i++) {
        student.addGrade(sc.nextDouble());
    }
    return student;
}
```

}

This is where the StudentMap is decalred:

```
public class StudentViewController {
//student version number

private double versionNum = 1.0;
//A boolean to check if the Student file has been altered
private static boolean dirtyByte = false;
//a scanner to take in input data for operations
private Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//A tree map to store the students
private TreeMap<String, Student> studentMap = new TreeMap<String, Student>();
//a String to take in input option
String input;
//Name of the current file being written or read
private static String currentFileName = "";
```

Comment: Can we see the how and where `studentMap` is declared?

Comment: better to put line number as key and line contents as values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the newly created `Student` returned from the `ReadStudent()` method to your map like this.

```
studentMap.put("aUniqueStringToIdentifyTheStudent", Student.ReadStudent(ReadFile));
```

One thing to note here is that, your `try-catch` should be inside a method within the class `StudentViewController` and not hanging around as such in `StudentViewController`.